# Change style of Dialog/DialogFragments

Tags: android, android-theme, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment, android-styles

How can I theme my app so all the `Dialogs` and `DialogFragments` have a specific theme? I've been trying to add items to my generated `AppTheme` (which has `android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` as parent in `styles.xml` but I can't find out which one is works. There are also some other changes in `AppTheme` that I need.
In my manifest, the theme of my `<application>` is set `@style/AppTheme`.
I'm using targetSdk 19 and minimumSdk 14.

The things I want to change is the title bar of the `Dialogs`.